# Package operation failed?

Tags: update-manager

While updating, I got this error in Update manager:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 

[...]

(Reading database ... 100%%

(Reading database ... 168216 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libasound2 1.0.25-1ubuntu10 (using .../libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libasound2 ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: data error'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1_i386.deb
Error in function:
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Update Manager got an error while extracting some files. Probably there was some problem while downloading the updates and some downloaded files may be corrupted.

To remove those files execute this on a terminal

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

This should delete all downloaded files. After that, run again Update Manager to redownload and install the updates.