# Wireless Networks Not getting Detected Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Wireless networks are not getting detected on my Ubuntu 12.04 after a restart. I did'nt install anything. Just installed the automatic updates after which I restarted my Laptop. Now its not detecting any of the wireless networks.

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux bblpt0196 3.5.0-54-generic #81~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

`lspci -nn` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge [1022:9600]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AMD RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx) [1043:9602]
00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3) [1022:9607]
00:0a.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5) [1022:9609]
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] [1002:4390]
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:12.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:13.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385] (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller [1002:439c]
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383]<br> 
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller [1002:439d]
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge [1002:4384]
00:14.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller [1002:4399]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0 [1022:1600]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1 [1022:1601]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2 [1022:1602]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3 [1022:1603]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4 [1022:1604]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5 [1022:1605]
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780L [Radeon 3000] [1002:9616]
01:05.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon (HD) 3000 Series] [1002:960f]
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1142]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
```

Comment: What's the model name of your wireless card? So it works before the update? Please open your terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and paste the `lspci -nn| grep Network` output back here. Thanks.

Comment: The output is blank. Yes it was working before the update

Comment: Interesting, it means that it's not detected, please paste the result of `lspci -nn`, thanks.

Comment: I am adding it as a comment since it is longer than 2450 characters, Thanks

Comment: @Lin Pls find the below Answer to see the output of the lspci - nn command

Comment: This could be a regression bug, please edit your question and paste the `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a` result as well, thanks.

Comment: I have done that Lin. Please help me resolving this bug, Thanks

Comment: If your BIOS has wireless settings, try to disable it from there, reboot, re-enable it. Silly but sometime it works.

Answer (score 0):

according to the clues you provided here, it looks like a regression to the kernel.

However, the kernel (3.5 Quantal) you're using has reached EOL (End-Of-Life).

I will suggest you to upgrade to the new HWE (Hardware Enablement Stack) support, which is kernel 3.13 Trusty, by following these steps:

1. Search for "update" in your dash
   [image]
2. Open the Update Manager and select the "Install" button here (You could upgrade to 14.04.1 as you wish.)
   [image]

If you have your system upgraded to 3.13 kernel, and it's still not working...
This issue should be reported as a bug, please use `ubuntu-bug linux` command in your terminal to open a bug report on [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net).

For more detail regrading filing bugs, you could follow this article: [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), or this guide: [how-do-i-report-a-bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Cheers.

Comment: Package operation failed

The installation or removal of a software package failed.

Comment: I did and restarted the system. But still the same issue.

Comment: Have you successfully upgraded to 3.13 kernel? You could check it with `uname -a`.

Comment: uname -a output -->                                                            Linux bblpt0196 3.5.0-54-generic #81~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: No, you didn't successfully upgrade your system, please try to solve your [Package operation failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/213818/package-operation-failed) issue first.

Comment: Kernel is still 3.5 i think. I have only one update remaining in the update Manage that is -> "Firmware for linux kernel drivers" which is getting failed when I install

Comment: Even After doing what has mentioned in the answer still my update is getting failed and showing the error as said in [http://askubuntu.com/questions/213818/package-operation-failed]

Comment: Please search on askubuntu.com with that, thanks

Comment: Lin I have corrected the problem but still its not detecting wireless networks. Now I am able to upgrade. The update List is Empty in the Update Manager