# Upgrade failed and Unable to Install update in Update Manager

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, package-management

I am unable to proceed with the upgrade or updateing via Update Manager. This is the Exception I am getting While upgrading. Please help.

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done The following packages will be upgraded:
 linux-firmware 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
Need to get 0 B/27.7 MB of archives. After this operation, 8,428 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
(Reading database ... 189869 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-firmware 1.79.1 (using .../linux-firmware_1.79.16_all.deb)... 
Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ... 
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.16_all.deb (--unpack): 
trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ar3k/ramps_0x31010000_40.dfu', which is also in package bt-dw1705-firmware 0.1 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.16_all.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal and use following command

```
sudo dpkg --purge bt-dw1705-firmware
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After it try to update.

Comment: Thank You ! Tha Works. Please see my another question here and hope you could help on this too [https://askubuntu.com/questions/525086/wireless-networks-not-getting-detected-ubuntu-12-04/525090#525090]